# Rewrite URL crashes facebook sdk for php

Tags: php, facebook, mod-rewrite

I have this scenario.
On a MVC web app we are rewriting the url:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

So the url might be:

```
http://mysite.com/ControllerName/MethodName/Param1/Param2.......
```

Now we need to implement a facebook login on the app.
We simply copy and paste the code from the sdk page on git

```
require 'facebook-php-sdk/src/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'YOUR_APP_ID',
  'secret' => 'YOUR_APP_SECRET',
));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();
if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}
if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
}
```

Done this, the `$user`  is always 0, because facebook returns to the 'redirect_uri' with  `?key=parm` where the user information is located.

The actual URL redirected to by Facebook look like:

```
http://localhost/tesis/?state=6713ce83f25b296abd372ccad20a244d&code=AQA6xxwPiiQt06luKaDD84dFxIXPuhO41RlCQcnV5K2ZtVjyKvZ3A7uqqOQlEX4To_CoT8nEmUjzS2YOVsdhU5CE3I_jfK2LsmkpLsty91-EeipIIvFQLqe6VFB_OHYcj_J0-jdhXfAdYFQ2jsA6Hejnw8bF1ezWtEaZCNnqgc_mQWhovkV8XmFzLFGsqjr52bq2b0wR8Au3ZOSvJUnperaT#_=_
```

So I suppose I need to make some modifications on the htaccess.
But I don't know what changes I need to do

Comment: What does the actual URL redirected to by Facebook look like, and what does it look like internally after your rewriting? Following the server-side Auth flow, the SDK will be looking for the `state` and `code` parameter – so these have to be passed as GET parameters in the query string for the SDK to find them inside of $_REQUEST as expected. If your rewriting translates those into path components, the SDK will not recognize them. (In that case, you could still set them in $_REQUEST yourself before initializing the SDK.)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.
I just redirect to the main page in the login url like this:

```
$params = array('scope' => 'email','redirect_uri' => 'http://www.page.com/index.php');
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
```

May be you can redirect to a "Success login" page (non URL friendly) and include a link to back history.

Comment: Still not working.. I think there is something worng or may be not all the modules of apache for achive this are active.